# bootsrapping in django

Tags: django

while using groovy with grails i used to use the bootstrap file to add some data such as the primary user of the application or other things that need to be initialised for the first time when the application is started , how do i achive the same in django?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want fixtures.

See [Providing initial data for models](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures) in the Django docs for more information.